# Removing nvd3 angular charts

Tags: angularjs, typescript, nvd3.js

I have a directive which - based on the bound data and meta data - displays either a line chart or a bar chart. I use nvd3 to display those charts and displaying the first time works fine. But when the metadata changes and the charttype should change, I see both.

This is my link function:

```
link: (scope: IReportChartScope, element: JQuery, attrs) => {
    currentElement = element;

    scope.$watch('diagramInfo', (newVal: IDiagramInformation, oldVal: IDiagramInformation, scp: IReportChartScope) => {
        if (innerElement) {
            d3.select('#' + scope.diagramId + ' svg').remove();
            innerElement.remove();
        }

        if (!newVal) {
            currentElement.html(loadingDataTemplate);
        } else {
            var request = <IPeriodDiagramDataRequest>diagramInfo.Request;

            if (request.Period.Id == DiagramAggregationPeriod.All) {
                currentElement.html(barChartTemplate);
            } else {
                currentElement.html(lineChartTemplate);
            }
            innerElement = $compile(currentElement.contents())(scope);
        }
    });
}
```

You can see that in the beginning I try to remove the innerElement of my directive, but it somehow doesn't work. These are my templates:

```
var loadingDataTemplate = '<h1>Loading...</h1>';
var lineChartTemplate = '<nvd3-line-chart id="{{diagramId}}" data="diagramInfo.Series" showxaxis="true" showyaxis="true" tooltips="true" interactive="true" ' +
    'showlegend="true" width="{{width}}" height="{{height}}" nodata="Es wurden keine Daten geladen." margin="{top: 30, right: 30, bottom:30, left: 90}">' +
    '<svg ng-style="{width: width + \'px\', height: height + \'px\'}"></svg></nvd3-line-chart>';
var barChartTemplate = '<nvd3-multi-bar-chart id="{{diagramId}}" data="diagramInfo.Series" showxaxis="true" showyaxis="true" tooltips="true" interactive="true" ' +
    'showlegend="true" width="{{width}}" height="{{height}}" nodata="Es wurden keine Daten geladen." margin="{top: 30, right: 30, bottom:30, left: 90}">' +
    '<svg ng-style="{width: width + \'px\', height: height + \'px\'}"></svg></nvd3-multi-bar-chart>';
```

I don't want to use ng-if or ng-hide because the directive will have a bit more functionality. Any ideas how I can get rid of it? it's also interesting to prevent memory leaks from happening. I've found [How to avoid memory leaks using angularjs-nvd3-directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24821354/how-to-avoid-memory-leaks-using-angularjs-nvd3-directives) and used it for my inspiration, but probably not enough.

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27309825/angularjs-remove-method-is-not-working-on-ie11, it may help you.

Comment: Thanks, but it somehow didn't work, I also tried append, replaceWith, ... and all of them broke at some point. I ended up with the solution I described in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guess AngularJS wasn't built to be used this way, instead I defined a rather huge template file which consists of one `<div ng-include="chartTemplate"></div>` and a many `<script type="text/ng-template" id="xyzChart.html"/>...</script>`.

In my directive I now only define the template I want to use in chartTemplate and everything works like a charm. Although I'm not sure if this doesn't cause memory leaks, but let's take a problem at a time.